# preg_replace() with a match followed by a string that start with a number

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace a the content of href attribute with another URL

So I use this script

```
$html = 'data-content="111"';
$var_2 = "222";
$html = preg_replace('/(["\'])111\1/i',"$1$var_2$1",$html);
echo $html
```

The output was

```
data-content=22"
```

What I was expecting

```
data-content="222"
```

The problem is that the compiler look for match $12 because $var_2 start with the number "2"

I tried to edit the code like this but no luck

```
$html = preg_replace('/(["\'])111\1/i','$1'.$var_2.'$1',$html);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around this issue by using a 2-digit number (in this case `01`) for the replacement group:

```php
$html = 'data-content="111"';
$var_2 = "222";
$html = preg_replace('/(["\'])111\1/', "$01$var_2$1",$html);
echo $html;
```

Output:

```
data-content="222"
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ukuYQ)

You can also work around it using the method described in the `preg_replace` [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) page:

> When working with a replacement pattern where a backreference is immediately followed by another number (i.e.: placing a literal number immediately after a matched pattern), you cannot use the familiar \1 notation for your backreference. \11, for example, would confuse preg_replace() since it does not know whether you want the \1 backreference followed by a literal 1, or the \11 backreference followed by nothing. In this case the solution is to use ${1}1. This creates an isolated $1 backreference, leaving the 1 as a literal.

```php
$html = preg_replace('/(["\'])111\1/', '${1}' . "$var_2$1",$html);
```

Note in this case `${1}` must be enclosed in single quotes to prevent PHP from attempting to substitute it with the value of the variable `$1`. Note also that for the sample data the `i` (case-insensitive) flag to the regex is not required and I have removed it.

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/NUs7D)